# Joblib and memory-bound parallelization

Tags: python, memory, parallel-processing, joblib

In Python, [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) provides a really nice tool for performing embarrassingly parallel execution.  I'm kind of new to it and I'm trying to figure out how to handle potentially memory-bound jobs.

For example, consider the following:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np

num_workers=8
num_jobs=100
memory_range=1000

def my_function(x):
    np.random.seed(x)
    array_length=(np.random.randint(memory_range)+1)**3
    big_list_of_numbers=np.random.uniform(array_length)
    return(np.sum(big_list_of_numbers))

results=Parallel(n_jobs=num_workers)(delayed(my_function)(i) for i in range(num_jobs))
```

The memory usage for each job could vary from a few hundred bytes up to about 0.8 GB.

In a perfect world, I'd like to give joblib some aggregate memory budget (like "I want to be 99% sure that my total memory usage across all workers is < 8GB"), have joblib estimate the distribution of memory usage of the jobs it has seen so far, and use that to dynamically resize the worker pool.

Unfortunately, it seems (?) that the number of active workers is statically determined when you invoke Parallel().  If that is the case, I could use resource.getrusage() to figure out the memory usage from a few sample jobs, estimated the distribution myself, and use a fixed cap.  If memory usage is highly variable, this would be either dangerous or inefficient.

If I were parallelizing one particular function, I would simply profile it and be done.  However, for my application I will not know the function in advance.

I would prefer not to reinvent this wheel.  So, my questions are:

1. Does joblib support any part of this functionality?
2. Does some other (hopefully simple) tool?

Comment: Part of the problem is that in real-world scenarios, memory usage changes over time. Job A might consume little memory in the first 15 minutes of its runtime - so why not start many other workers? Only that then the heavy memory usage of A kicks, so you'd have to stall the other workers - new functionality needed. And that is still somewhat benevolent. Imagine: Memory is depeleted, but every worker needs more to continue.

Comment: That's an excellent observation, @JannPoppinga, but if we have many more workers than jobs (which should be a common case), then we should have the opportunity to observe the full life cycle of some workers before we process most of the queue.  Your broader point ("this can be really messy") is well taken, and may have some bearing on why no one has answered this question in the past 7 years :)

Comment: It would be very hard to generically learn a prediction. In my case, memory footprint *wildly* varies depending on the number of triangles in a 3D model *and* the model's complexity. However, it should be pretty simple for joblib to offload this to the user. I would tell it: Never process more than 2M triangles at once and then how many triangles each job has (using worst case for complexity).

Comment: I think you *can* offload that to joblib in the example you give, @JannPoppinga-- the user estimates worst case memory usage (through worst-case complexity for triangle count, in your example), divides system memory by worker memory, and uses that to cap the worker count.  But my concern is that we are leaving resources on the table.  I realize it's a non-trivial regression problem, but if, for instance, you supplied Joblib++ with the triangle count for each job and it observed worker memory usage, it could figure out the relationship itself.  Any solution would be imperfect, but I'd use it!

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood your comment-- are you essentially suggesting that each worker provide an estimate of resource usage, and the worker queue is provided with a cap for the sum?  So if each worker provides a job-specific memory estimate, we're done?  Then any fancy memory prediction falls on the user, but that's OK.  Yes!  That's a great idea.  And whether the resource is memory or bandwidth or something else, you could still globally control it.